# Proof of the identity $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}dx=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha/2)\Gamma(1-\alpha/2)}{2\Gamma(\alpha)}$ for $\alpha\in (0,2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $0<\alpha<2.$ Looking for a proof for the following: $$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}dx=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha/2)\Gamma(1-\alpha/2)}{2\Gamma(\alpha)}.$$

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Trying to use Fubini theorem, like the cases $\alpha=1,\alpha=\frac{1}{2},$ considering $\sin(x)e^{-xy}$ or $\sin(x)e^{xy^2},$ so looking for a way (an expression to use Fubini).

Comment: From the case cases $\alpha=1,\alpha=\frac{1}{2},$ and using $\Gamma$ function, I found $\frac{1}{x^\alpha}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-xy}y^{\alpha-1}dy$

Comment: So in order to use Fubini, taking $w>0,\int_0^w\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}dx=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}y^{\alpha-1}(\int_0^{w}\sin(x)e^{-xy}dx)dy=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-wy}(y\sin(w)+\cos(w))}{y^2+1}dy,$ then using Dominated convergence theorem, taking $w \to +\infty,$ we find $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}dx=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x^2+1}dx$

Comment: Conclusion: Since $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x^2+1}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1u^{\alpha/2-1}(1-u)^{-\alpha/2}du=\frac{1}{2}B(\alpha/2,1-\alpha/2)=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\alpha/2)\Gamma(1-\alpha/2)$ (Taking $x=\sqrt{(1-u)/u}$)

Comment: Using this formula, we can compute $\int_0^{+\infty}\sin(x^\alpha)dx,$ for $|\alpha|>1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought that it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on a useful property of the Laplace Transform (See [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis)) to evaluate integrals over the positive reals.  To that end we proceed.

---

Let $F(s)=s^{-\alpha}$, $0<\alpha<2$ and $f(t)=\sin(t)$.  Then, the inverse Laplace Transform of $F(s)$ is

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{F\}(x)=\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\tag1$$

and the Laplace Transform of $f(t)$ is given by

$$\mathscr{L}\{f\}(x)=\frac1{x^2+1}\tag2$$

---

Then, using $(1)$ and $(2)$ along with [This Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) of the Laplace Transform, we assert that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,dx=\frac1{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x^2+1}\,dx\tag3$$

---

The integral on the right-hand side of $(3)$ can be evaluated using a host of methodologies [See This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913325/real-analysis-methods-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracxa1x2-dx-a1), and is given by

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x^2+1}\,dx =\frac\pi{2\sin(\pi\alpha/2)} \tag4$$

---

Substituting $(4)$ in $(3)$, we find that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2\Gamma(\alpha)\sin(\pi \alpha/2)}\tag5$$

---

Finally, using the reflection formula for the Gamma Function ([See this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913325/real-analysis-methods-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracxa1x2-dx-a1/1913576#1913576)) as given by $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}$, we arrive at the expected result

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha/2)\Gamma(1-\alpha/2)}{2\Gamma(\alpha)}}$$

as was to be shown!

---

**ALTERNATIVE METHODOLOGY:  CONTOUR INTEGRATION**

We begin by analyzing the closed-contour integral $I(\alpha)$, $\alpha\in (0,2)$ given by

$$\begin{align}
I(\alpha)&=\int_\varepsilon^R \frac{e^{ix}}{x^\alpha}\,dx+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{iRe^{i\phi}}}{(Re^{i\phi})^\alpha}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&-\int_\varepsilon^R \frac{e^{-x}}{(ix)^\alpha}\,i\,dx-\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}}}{(\varepsilon 
 e^{i\phi})^\alpha}\,i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\tag6
\end{align}$$

If we choose the branch cut of the natural logarithm to originate at $0$ and extend to the point at infinity along the real axis, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that $I(\alpha)=0$.  Furthermore, it is straightforward to show that as $R\to\infty$, the second integral on the right-hand side of $(6)$ vanishes.

So far, after letting $R\to\infty$ and then taking the imaginary parts of all terms in $(6)$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_\varepsilon^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,dx&=\sin\left(\frac{\pi (1-\alpha)}2\right)\int_\varepsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x^\alpha}\,dx\\\\
&+\varepsilon^{1-\alpha}\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-\varepsilon \sin(\phi)}\cos\left((1-\alpha)\phi+\varepsilon \cos(\phi)\right)\,d\phi\tag7
\end{align}$$

The last term on the right-hand side can be written as

$$\varepsilon^{1-\alpha}\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-\varepsilon \sin(\phi)}\cos\left((1-\alpha)\phi+\varepsilon \cos(\phi)\right)\,d\phi=\varepsilon^{1-\alpha}\frac{\sin(\pi (1-\alpha)/2)}{1-\alpha}+O(\varepsilon^{2-\alpha})\tag8$$

Using $(8)$ in $(7)$, integrating by parts the first integral on the right-hand side of $(7)$ with $u=e^{-x}$ and $v=\frac{1}{(1-\alpha)x^{\alpha-1}}$, letting $\varepsilon\to0^+$, and exploiting the aforementioned reflection formula $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac\pi{\sin(\pi x)}$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_\varepsilon^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,dx&=\frac{\sin\left(\pi (1-\alpha)/2\right)}{1-\alpha}\int_\varepsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x^{\alpha-1}}\,dx\\\\
&=\sin\left(\frac{\pi(1-\alpha)}2\right)\Gamma(1-\alpha)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi \sin\left(\frac{\pi (1-\alpha)}2\right)}{\sin(\pi \alpha)\Gamma(\alpha)}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\Gamma(\alpha)\sin(\pi \alpha/2)}\\\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha/2)\Gamma(1-\alpha/2)}{2\Gamma(\alpha)}
\end{align}$$

which agrees with the result obtained in the previous section!

Comment: Is there a real analysis method to prove the reflection formula?

Comment: Concerning the above question, I solved it using dominated convergence theorem (more details in the above comments)

Comment: Hi, didn't saw you messages, concerning your answer, it looks good!

Comment: @kurt.w.x Thank you Kurt.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your effort

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 8):

The [Mellin transform](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html) of $\sin{t}$ (as proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382412/mellin-transform-of-sin-x-aka-int-infty-0-xs-1-sin-x-dx)) yields:

$$\mathcal{I}(z)=\int_0^{\infty} t^{z-1} \sin{t} \; \mathrm{d}t =\Gamma\left(z\right)\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}z\right)}, \; -1 < \Re \left(z\right) < 1$$

And your integral is:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{I}(1-\alpha) &= \Gamma\left(1-\alpha\right)\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-\alpha\right)\right)} \\
&= \Gamma\left(1-\alpha\right) \left( \frac{\pi }{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-\alpha}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{2}\right)} \right) \\
&=\Gamma\left(1-\alpha\right) \left(\frac{\pi \sin{\left(\pi \alpha\right)} \Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) }{2 \pi^2} \right) \\
&=\Gamma\left(1-\alpha\right) \left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) }{2 \Gamma\left(\alpha\right) \Gamma \left(1-\alpha\right)} \right) \\
&= \boxed{\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin{(x)}}{x^{\alpha}} \; \mathrm{d}x =\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) }{2 \Gamma\left(\alpha\right)}, \; 0< \Re\left(\alpha\right)<2} 
\end{align*}

Where Euler's reflection formula and the Legendre relation were utilized to get the desired form of the answer: $$\Gamma\left(\alpha\right)\Gamma\left(1-\alpha\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sin{\left(\pi \alpha\right)}}$$
$$\pi^2=\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\sin{\left(\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}\right)} \cos{\left(\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}\right)} \color{blue}{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1-\alpha}{2}\right)} $$

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x^{\alpha}}\,\dd x}
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ \root{x}}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{\root{x}} \over x^{\alpha/2}}
\pars{{1 \over 2}\,x^{-1/2}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\pars{\color{red}{1 - \alpha/2}} - 1}\,
{\sin\pars{\root{x}} \over \root{x}}\,\dd x
\end{align}
Note that
$\ds{{\sin\pars{\root{x}} \over \root{x}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}\,{x^{k} \over \pars{2k + 1}!} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\color{red}{\Gamma\pars{k + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{2k + 2}}\,{\pars{-x}^{k} \over k!}}$.

With Ramanujan-MT:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x^{\alpha}}\,\dd x} =
{1 \over 2}\,\Gamma\pars{1 - {\alpha \over 2}}
\color{red}{\Gamma\pars{\color{black}{-\bracks{1 - \alpha/2}} + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{2\color{black}{\braces{-\bracks{1 - \alpha/2}}} + 2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{1 \over 2}\,\Gamma\pars{1 - {\alpha \over 2}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{\alpha/2} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}} =
{\pi \over 2}{\csc\pars{\pi\alpha/2} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}} \\ &
\end{align}