# Integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi\;\Gamma\big(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\big)}{2^\alpha\; \Gamma\big(\frac{1+\alpha}{2}\big)}$

Tags: probability, integration

Lemma 1 in  [Szekely G J , Rizzo M L.(2005)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00357-005-0012-9) has such equation:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi\;\Gamma\big(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}\big)}{2^\alpha\; \Gamma\big(\frac{1+\alpha}{2}\;\big)},\quad\alpha\in(0,2).$$
I don't know how to prove this equation, please give me some hints or reference.

Comment: Deform the contour to the imaginary axis.

Comment: Here is [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Maybe lengthen the question a bit more with some research on how to solve it.

Comment: See any of the answers in [Proof of the identity $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}dx=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha/2)\Gamma(1-\alpha/2)}{2\Gamma(\alpha)}$ for $\alpha\in (0,2)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806166/int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-alphadx-frac-gamma-alpha-2-gamma1-alph?noredirect=1) and use the Legendre duplication formula to convert the closed form given in the linked question to yours.