# Integrate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin\frac {1}{x^2} dx$

Tags: integration

The limit of $\sin\frac{1}{x^2}$ when $x\to0$ does not exist but this integral can be calculated, the result is $\sqrt{2\pi}$, can anyone explain?

Comment: Observe that the integral is symmetric. So it is $2\int_0^\infty \sin(1/x^2)dx$. Now change the integration variable from $x$ to $t$ by $t=1/x^2$, and use https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3806166

Comment: If you're having trouble to translate from your language to English, try [this](https://translate.google.com/). It's not perfect, but it works.

Comment: @jjagmath https://www.deepl.com/translator is probably better.

Comment: This can be related to a special Integral called as "Fresnel integral". It has applications in quantum physics.