# Mellin transform of sin(x) .

Tags: integration, contour-integration, mellin-transform

[Proof of the identity $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}dx=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha/2)\Gamma(1-\alpha/2)}{2\Gamma(\alpha)}$ for $\alpha\in (0,2)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806166/proof-of-the-identity-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-alphadx-frac-gamma/3814852#3814852)

In the above post, in the 2nd answer (given by mark viola) - in the 2nd part - "ALTERNATIVE METHODOLOGY: CONTOUR INTEGRATION"
equation no 8 goes to zero as $\varepsilon\to0^+$ only if $\alpha <1$
but we need to prove the identity for $\alpha\in (0,2)$.
Is the proof incomplete then? If it's incomplete then how to extend the proof upto $\alpha < 2$.

Comment: Use analytic continuation in $\alpha$.

Comment: We could simply use the analytical continuation approach. The proof is rigorous for $\alpha\in(0;1)$, and the answer (and the initial integral) are well defined for $\alpha\in(0;2)$.

Comment: Note that after arriving at $(8)$, I proceeded to integrate by parts.  Then, I took the limit as $\varepsilon\to 0^+$, which leads to a result that is valid for $\alpha\in (0,2)$

Comment: Ah. Got it. thanks