# How to solve $y-y''=x^a$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, gamma-function

I need to solve this differential equation
$$y-y''=x^a$$
I am not well-versed in differential equations.
I found the complementary solution first, and that was simple
$$y-y''=0$$
$$y_c=C_1\cosh x+C_2\sinh x$$
I could not find the particular solution. I tried to induce a pattern based on specific cases of $a$
$$y_p=\frac{7!}{7!}x^7+\frac{7!}{5!}x^5+\frac{7!}{3!}x^3+\frac{7!}{1!}x, \space a=7$$
$$y_p=\frac{6!}{6!}x^6+\frac{6!}{4!}x^4+\frac{6!}{2!}x^2+\frac{6!}{0!},\space a=6$$
$$y_p=\sum_{n=0}^{⌊a/2⌋}\frac{a!}{(a-2n)!}x^{a-2n}$$
I think this solution works only when $a$ is a natural number. When I plug in $a=1/2$, I get 0, but WA says the solution requires the incomplete gamma function, so the solution is clearly not a polynomial. How can I solve this differential equation?

[a = 0.5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y-y%27%27%3Dx%5E0.5)

[general case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y-y%27%27%3Dx%5Ea)

Comment: If $a$ is a positive integer, then the RHS $x^a$ is appropriate to use in the method of undetermined coefficients.  But for other values of $a$, that is no longer true.  So (as @Moo suggests) variation of parameters can be used.  Maple writes its solution in terms of Whitaker M and incomplete gamma functions.

Comment: @Moo what you wrote is equivalent to what Op wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{gather*}
\boxed{y-y^{\prime \prime}-x^{\alpha}=0}
\end{gather*}
Let the solution be
$$
y = y_h + y_p 
$$
Where $y_h$ is the solution to the homogeneous ODE and $y_p$ is a particular solution to the non-homogeneous ODE.
The homogeneous solution $y_h$ can be easily found to be
$$
y_h = c_{1} {\mathrm e}^{-x}+c_{2} {\mathrm e}^{x}
$$
The particular solution $y_p$ can be found using the method of variation of parameters.
Let
\begin{align*}
y_p(x) &= u_1 y_1 +  u_2 y_2\tag{1} 
\end{align*}
Where $u_1,u_2$ to be determined, and $y_1,y_2$ are the two basis
solutions (the two linearly independent solutions of the homogeneous ODE) found earlier when solving the homogeneous ODE as
\begin{align*}
y_1 &= {\mathrm e}^{-x}\\
y_2 &= {\mathrm e}^{x}
\end{align*}
In the Variation of parameters $u_1,u_2$ are found using
\begin{align*}
u_1 &= -\int \frac{y_2 f(x)}{a W(x)}\tag{2} \\
u_2  &=  \int \frac{y_1 f(x)}{a W(x)}
\end{align*}
Where $W(x)$ is the Wronskian and $a$ is the coefficient in front of $y''$ in the given ODE. The Wronskian is given by $W=
\begin{vmatrix}
y_1             & y_{2} \\ 
y_{1}^{\prime}  & y_{2}^{\prime}
\end{vmatrix}
$. Hence
$$
W = \begin{vmatrix}
{\mathrm e}^{-x} & {\mathrm e}^{x} \\ 
\frac{d}{dx}\left({\mathrm e}^{-x}\right) & \frac{d}{dx}\left({\mathrm e}^{x}\right)
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Which simplifies to
\begin{align*}
W = 2
\end{align*}
Therefore Eq. (2) becomes
\begin{align*}
u_1 &= - \int -\frac{{\mathrm e}^{x} x^{\alpha}}{2}d x
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
u_1 &= -\frac{\left(-1\right)^{-\alpha} \left(x^{\alpha} \left(-1\right)^{\alpha} \alpha  \Gamma \left(\alpha \right) \left(-x \right)^{-\alpha}-x^{\alpha} \left(-1\right)^{\alpha} {\mathrm e}^{x}-x^{\alpha} \left(-1\right)^{\alpha} \alpha  \left(-x \right)^{-\alpha} \Gamma \left(\alpha , -x \right)\right)}{2}\\
    &= \frac{x^{\alpha} \left(\left(\Gamma \left(\alpha , -x \right) \alpha -\Gamma \left(\alpha +1\right)\right) \left(-x \right)^{-\alpha}+{\mathrm e}^{x}\right)}{2}\\
u_2 &= \int \frac{{\mathrm e}^{-x} x^{\alpha}}{-2}\,dx\\
&= -\frac{x^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} {\mathrm e}^{-\frac{x}{2}} \operatorname{WhittakerM}\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}, \frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{1}{2}, x\right)}{2 \left(\alpha +1\right)}\\
u_2 &= -\frac{x^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} {\mathrm e}^{-\frac{x}{2}} \operatorname{WhittakerM}\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}, \frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{1}{2}, x\right)}{2 \alpha +2}
\end{align*}
Therefore the particular solution, from equation (1)  is
\begin{align*}
y_p(x) = \frac{{\mathrm e}^{-x} \left(\left(\alpha +1\right) \left(\left(\Gamma \left(\alpha , -x \right) \alpha -\Gamma \left(\alpha +1\right)\right) \left(-x \right)^{-\alpha}+{\mathrm e}^{x}\right) x^{\alpha}-x^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \operatorname{WhittakerM}\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}, \frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{1}{2}, x\right) {\mathrm e}^{\frac{3 x}{2}}\right)}{2 \alpha +2}
\end{align*}
The general solution is
\begin{align*}
y &= y_h + y_p\\
&= \left(c_{1} {\mathrm e}^{-x}+c_{2} {\mathrm e}^{x}\right) + \left(\frac{{\mathrm e}^{-x} \left(\left(\alpha +1\right) \left(\left(\Gamma \left(\alpha , -x \right) \alpha -\Gamma \left(\alpha +1\right)\right) \left(-x \right)^{-\alpha}+{\mathrm e}^{x}\right) x^{\alpha}-x^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \operatorname{WhittakerM}\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}, \frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{1}{2}, x\right) {\mathrm e}^{\frac{3 x}{2}}\right)}{2 \alpha +2}\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Look at the equation in $2D$,

Let $a>0$ and $\mathbf Y = \begin{bmatrix}
y'\\ y
\end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf b(x) = \begin{bmatrix}
x^a\\ 0
\end{bmatrix}$ then $$\mathbf Y' = \mathbf A \mathbf Y + \mathbf b(x)$$

The solution of the this DE will be:

$$\mathbf Y(x) = \int_{0}^{x} e^{-(x-t)\mathbf A} \mathbf b(t)\mathrm dt + e^{-x\mathbf A}\mathbf Y_0$$

Since $$\mathbf A = \mathbf U \mathbf D \mathbf U^\intercal$$ with $\mathbf U = \frac1{\sqrt 2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf D = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ then,

$$e^{t\mathbf A} = \mathbf U e^{t\mathbf D}\mathbf U^{\intercal} = \begin{bmatrix}\cosh(t) & \sinh(t) \\ \sinh(t) & \cosh(t)\end{bmatrix}$$

So,

\begin{align}
\mathbf Y(x) &= \int_0^x \begin{bmatrix}\cosh(x-t) & -\sinh(x-t) \\ -\sinh(x-t) & \cosh(x-t)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} t^a \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\mathrm d t + \begin{bmatrix}\cosh(x) & -\sinh(x) \\ -\sinh(x) & \cosh(x)\end{bmatrix}\mathbf Y_0\\
&= \int_0^x \begin{bmatrix} t^a\cosh(x-t) \\ -t^a\sinh(x-t) \end{bmatrix}\mathrm dt + \begin{bmatrix}\cosh(x) & -\sinh(x) \\ -\sinh(x) & \cosh(x)\end{bmatrix}\mathbf Y_0
\end{align}

Finally,

$$y(x) = -\int_0^x t^a \sinh(x-t)\mathrm d t + y_0\cosh(x) - y'_0\sinh(x)$$

Since,

\begin{align}
\int_0^x t^{a} \sinh(x-t)\mathrm d t &= \frac12 e^{x}\int_0^x t^a e^{-t}\mathrm dt -\frac12e^{-x}\int_0^x t^a e^{t}\mathrm dt 
\end{align}

Your expression can be expressed your solution using incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 1):

Proposing for the particular $y_p(x) = c(x)\cosh x$ after substitution in the complete ODE we obtain

$$
\sinh(x)c''(x)+2\cosh(x)c'(x)+x^a=0
$$

now calling $z(x) = c'(x)$ we follow with

$$
\sinh(x)z'(x)+2\cosh(x)z(x)+x^a=0
$$

The homogeneous have solution

$$
z_h(x) = c_1 \text{csch}^2(x)
$$

then choosing as particular $z_p(x) = c_1(x)\text{csch}^2(x)$ and substituting into the $z(x)$ complete ODE we have

$$
\text{csch}(x) c_1'(x)+x^a=0
$$

so we have

$$
c_1(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^{a+1} (E_{-a}(-x)-E_{-a}(x))
$$

then going backwards

$$
z_h = \left(\frac{1}{2} x^{a+1} (E_{-a}(-x)-E_{-a}(x))\right)\text{csch}^2(x)
$$

and

$$
c(x) = \int z_h(\eta)d\eta = \frac{1}{2} \left(x^a (-x)^{-a} (\coth (x)-1) \Gamma (a+1,-x)+(\coth (x)+1) \Gamma (a+1,x)\right)
$$

and thus we have the particular

$$
y_p = \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(x^a (-x)^{-a} (\coth (x)-1) \Gamma (a+1,-x)+(\coth (x)+1) \Gamma (a+1,x)\right)\right)\cosh x
$$

NOTE

$E_a(x)$ is the exponential integral function.